# Normalize Axis between 0 and 1 in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a size of axis say from 1 to 100 and i want to plot some values by using normalized axis values with 0 to 1 instead of 1 to 100. Any body have some suggestion. Thanks

Comment: Unclear what your problem is. If you want to force the axis of a plot to be between 0 and 1 regardless of the data use `xlim([0 1])`. If you need to normalize the data set then what's wrong with dividing your x vector by 100?

Answer (score 1):

You could either (A) create custom labels or (B) change the data. Option (B) is more flexible and probably easier to do in most cases: rather than doing `plot(someX, someY);`, do `plot(someX / 100, someY)`.

Option (A) involves changing the `XTickLabel` property: `plot(someX, someY, 'XTickLabel', {'0.0', '0.25, '0.5', '1.0'}, 'XTick', [0, 25, 50, 100])` This is much less flexible since

> These labels replace the numeric labels generated by MATLAB. If you do
>   not specify enough text labels for all the tick marks, MATLAB uses all
>   of the labels specified, then reuses the specified labels.

according to http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes_props.html. That is also the reason you have to specify the actual ticks. If you do not, they will be generated dynamically at essentially arbitrary positions.